# Can someone identify this unusual plane at SeaTac airport?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I saw this plane at the SeaTac Airport and thought it was very unusual. The wings look too small to even be functional to me. What kind of plane is this and what is it used for?

[image]

Comment: That's my plane, look you can see me in the cockpit.  When the ceiling is too low to fly I can fold the wings and drive down the highway!

Comment: It's the little-known passenger version of the F-104 Starfighter. That thing sticking out of the front is a landing skid.

Comment: A rare variant without the AWACS dome.  Had issues with fine yaw control authority.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a big clue right underneath the "Sea-Tac Airport" decal - it says

> FIRE RESCUE

It can be seen a little better on this image

[image]
<sub>[source: wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SeaTac_fire_rescue_plane_01.jpg)</sub>

It is a rig used for fire and evacuation training.

> A unique tool the department uses is an aircraft mock-up designed for aircraft approach, entry and tactics training on the airfield. The smoke generated is not harmful to the environment and provides a realistic challenge.
>   <sub>source: https://www.portseattle.org/page/training</sub>

The image below appears to show it in use:

[image]

Comment: ie : It's not an airplane at all.

Comment: @J...  yes it is -- just one that can't fly.  Ya know, like the  emu of aircraft :-)

Comment: [a vehicle ***designed for air travel*** that has wings and one or more engines](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aeroplane) - so strictly speaking, it is not an aeroplane.

Comment: "big clue" I can read it now I know what it's supposed to say, but otherwise... I'll get more coffee.

Comment: is it an abstract mockup, or did they make it from an old aircraft that would have otherwise been scrapped?

Comment: @DanNeely looks like a mockup to me. The engine fans dont look real, doesnt look an awful lot like a current or past air frame AFAIK. I might be wrong though,

Comment: This is a complete guess, but I'd imagine that some parts will have come from scrapped aircraft and others will have been manufactured to make it look a little more real. Looks like the centre of the fuselage (including doors and windows), the inner part of the wing and the engine shells are real, while the fuselage nose and tail, outer wings, engine pylons and fans are fake.

Comment: Better pics:  https://twitter.com/seatacairport/status/857633066386243584?lang=en  
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/SeaTac_fire_rescue_plane_01.jpg

Comment: In what sense is this a "unique tool"? Most airports have a plane or mock-up plane used to train fire crews, don't they?

Comment: @DavidRicherby, that page is written like a promo for their department.  I'd say unique in the sense that any non-airport fire department wouldn't have that tool.  Perhaps it's "the only one in the area".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Or maybe most airports can affort to use an actual plane filled with fuel instead of using a cheap mock up...

Comment: So why the heck can the (mockup) wings fold??

Comment: @Fattie so there are wings in the way when doing training, but it doesn't take up as much space the rest of the time.

Comment: smart, @DanNeely !!!!

Comment: @Dan Neely Perhaps also the wings fold so that it could be transported by trailer from its manufacturer to the customer (Sea Tac airport).  Unlikely that this was manufactured on site...

Answer (score 3):

According to [this forum post](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/alaska-airlines-mileage-plan/872126-funny-looking-seatac-plane.html) about a **Funny Looking SEATAC Plane** it's a (fake) firefighter training plane.

Question:

> On 9/30 taxing north from SEA to ORD there was a 
>   funny looking tri-jet plane marked with Seattle 
>   Tacoma Airport hanging out by the Alaska Airlines 
>   cargo area. Wings folded up. Anyone know anything 
>   about this plane or its purpose?

Answer:

> Yeah, it's the **firefighter training plane . 
>   You hear pilots asking ATC what it is occasionally.**
>
> Here's a picture I found on flickr.
>   http://www.flickr.com/photos/smartjunco/331183916/